# sum up counts in shell

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I would like to sum up integers per line. I have a data file where I extract information.

I use this command to extract 7th information in column 10 that has value more than 0.25 . I would like to get the total number of integers having more than 0.25 value. But I'm getting a list of integers that are more than 0.25

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR>1{split($10,a,":"); count10[a[7]]++} END {for (i in count10) if (i>0.25) print i, count10[i]}' mygene.vcf
```

sample output that I'm getting now :

```
0.689 7
0.648 9
0.607 83
0.279 26
```

what I require:

```
125
```

sample data (10th column)

```
1/1:27:0,27:0,37:0:0,0.741:1.0:0:98:0,59.0
1/0:26:15,11:35,37:0:0.733,0.727:0.423:0:28:56.9,60.0
1/1:55:0,55:0,38:0:0,0.527:1.0:0:183:0,59.6
1/0:49:26,23:36,36:0:0.615,0.739:0.469:0:47:60.0,58.5
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically already have it. Instead of doing a print for each iteration of the `for` loop, accumulate into a sum and print that:

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR>1 {split($10,a,":"); 
                  count10[a[7]]++} 
            END  {for (i in count10) 
                    if (i>0.25) 
                      sum += count10[i];
                  print sum }' mygene.vcf
```